# Javascript: Error when setting background color based on select option

Tags: javascript

I recently started to learn Javascript, but I got stuck in one of my exercises.

I'm trying to change the color of the all the form `label` when a color in the `<select>` is chosen for the background, but I'm getting the same error.

> "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined"

Can someone help me out?

```js
function changeBackground(x){

 var body = document.getElementById('body');
 body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;

 if (x.value == red) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('label').style.color = 'grey';
 } else if (x.value == blue) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('label').style.color = 'white';
 } else if (x.value == green) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('label').style.color = 'yellow';
 }
 
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
   <div class="header">
      <h1 id="heading">Learning Javascript</h1>
   </div>

   <form method="post" action="something.php" name="myForm">
      <div>
         <label>First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstName" id="
  firstName">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div>
         <label>Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div>
         <label>Background</label>
         <select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <br>

      <input type="submit" name="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz In the `<script>` block at the bottom...

Comment: There will be a `Reference Error` in the console of your browser.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz this is an english speaking platform so also comments should be in english, so that everyone can follow the conversation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change all `label` colors, you must loop trough each one, since `getElementsByTagName` returns an array (live collection) of tags.

Also, your error was because you are making the wrong `if` statement, comparing to a variable, not to a string, (eg `red` instead of `"red"`)

```js
function changeBackground(x){
  var body = document.getElementById('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  var color;
  
  if (x.value == 'red') {
     color = 'grey';
    
  } else if (x.value == 'blue') {
     color = 'white';
    
  } else if (x.value == 'green') {
     color = 'yellow';
     
  }
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < labels.length; i++){
    var lbl = labels[i];
    lbl.style.color = color;
  }     
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div class="header">
      <h1 id="heading">Learning Javascript</h1>
  </div>

  <form method="post" action="something.php" name="myForm">
      <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" id="
      firstName">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
          <label>Background</label>
          <select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName('label')` returns a `HTMLCollection` what is an array like object, and this does not have a property with the name `style`.

So for `document.getElementsByTagName('label').style.color = 'grey';` the property `style` is `undefined`.

Comment: It returns [a live HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), actually.

Comment: @Andreas that's true, but the question is not about a reference error. For the given code the `ReferenceError`would occur before the `undefined` error,  so either the error isn't about the given code at all, or the OP had defined `red`, `green`, `blue` anywhere else.

Comment: You're right. I forgot the title and only had the unspecific _"but I'm getting the same error."_ in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Two things goes initially wrong here:

- quote your color name text, e.g. `x.value == "red"`
- `document.getElementsByTagName('label')` returns a *list of nodes*, so it needs a `[0]`

If you need to change color on all `label`'s, you need to loop through them.

```js
function changeBackground(x) {

  var body = document.getElementById('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;
  var color, labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

  if (x.value == "red") {
    color = 'grey';
  } else if (x.value == "blue") {
    color = 'white';
  } else if (x.value == "green") {
    color = 'yellow';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].style.color = color;
  }

}
```

```html
<body id="body">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="heading">Learning Javascript</h1>
  </div>


  <form method="post" action="something.php" name="myForm">
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="
  firstName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Background</label>
      <select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
```

---

Still, change styles inline is not recommended, use classes instead, like this

```js
function changeBackground(x) {
  document.getElementById('body').className = x.value;
}
```

```css
body.red {
    background-color: red;
}
body.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
body.green {
    background-color: green;
}

body.red label {
    color: gray;
}
body.blue label {
    color: white;
}
body.green label {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="heading">Learning Javascript</h1>
  </div>


  <form method="post" action="something.php" name="myForm">
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="
  firstName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Background</label>
      <select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

- You need to compare the colors in your `if statement` as a string like this: `"red"`
- Because `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array-like `live HTMLCollection`, you will need to use a loop to apply styling to all of them, or target specific ones like this: `document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0]`

```js
function changeBackground(x) {
  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
  var body = document.getElementById('body');
  body.style.backgroundColor = x.value;

  if (x.value == "red") {
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      labels[i].style.color = 'grey';
    }
  } else if (x.value == "blue") {
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      labels[i].style.color = 'white';
    }
  } else if (x.value == "green") {
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      labels[i].style.color = 'yellow';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="body">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="heading">Learning Javascript</h1>
  </div>


  <form method="post" action="something.php" name="myForm">
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="
        firstName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <label>Background</label>
      <select name="background" id="background" onchange="changeBackground(this)">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
```